Can org-sbe populate a whole table column?
Is it possible to populate table columns from org-sbe? The idea is that a code block would return multiple values, which would each end up in one cell of the designated column. This is what I have tried:
#+name: my-values
#+begin_src R :results value
  1:4
#+end_src

| Values            |
|-------------------|
| ((1) (2) (3) (4)) |
| ((1) (2) (3) (4)) |
| ((1) (2) (3) (4)) |
| ((1) (2) (3) (4)) |
#+tblfm: @2$1..@5$1='(org-sbe my-values)
#+tblfm: $1='(org-sbe my-values)

As you see, the result (with either of the two formulae) is that the entire return value is repeated in each cell, while I would like it to be distributed across the column. I have tried an elisp code block, too, with the same result.
This is the intended result:
| Values |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |


There is only one column in your table. Should there be four?

@NickD Sorry, I was not clear, I have clarified that the intended result is to have the values 1 to 4 in rows 2 to 5 of column 1.

OK - so apply the second formula in the answer to a single column table (or restrict the range to column 1 only), I'll add a note to the answer when I get back.

org-sbe returns a string: try evaluating this code block in the buffer:
#+begin_src elisp :results verbatim
(org-sbe my-values)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: "((1) (2) (3) (4))"

As you can see, it may look like a list, but it is unequivocally a string.
So in your first table formula, you are assigning this (constant) string to the single cell in each row, from row 2 to row 5, and column 1 (as I noted in my comment, there is only one column in your table). The second assigns the string to each row of column 1 but skips the first row because it is a heading, so it does the exact same thing.
Here's one way to do what (I think) you want:
#+name: my-values
#+begin_src R :results value
  1:4
#+end_src

| A | B | C | D |
|---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
#+tblfm: @2$1..@>$>='(car (nth (1- $#) (read (org-sbe my-values))))  

If you C-c C-c on the #+TBLFM: line, you'll get this table:

| A | B | C | D |
|---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

If instead, you want the transpose of this table, the formula has to use the row number to select the element (and you need to subtract 2 from it, since rows start from 2, not 1):
| A | B | C | D |
|---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
#+tblfm: @2$1..@>$>='(car (nth (- @# 2) (read (org-sbe my-values))))


EDIT: the OP has corrected my understanding of what he wanted: a single column like the A column above. That can be done with the last formula, e.g. by restricting the table to a single column (which implies that first column and last column are the same, i.e. column 1):
| Values |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
#+tblfm: @2$1..@>$>='(car (nth (- @# 2) (read (org-sbe my-values))))


Explanation: as discussed above, (org-sbe my-values) returns the string "((1) (2) (3) (4))". read converts the string into a Lisp data structure: the list ((1) (2) (3) (4)). We then apply various Lisp functions to select the thing we want: (nth 2 (read (org-sbe my-values))) returns the third element of the list, i.e. (3), because it counts from 0. We therefore use the column number minus 1, (1- $#), to select which element we want. Finally, (3) is a list consisting of the single element 3, so we use car to select that first element (that's equivalent to using nth with an argument of 0, but it is both shorter and more traditional). Putting it all together, we get (car (nth (1- $#) (read (org-sbe my-values)))) as shown.
The formula uses a range on the LHS: @2$1..@>$> is the rectangular (it is square in the example above, but it will be rectangular in general) region from row 2, column 1 to the last row (@>), last column ($>). See The Spreadsheet section in the manual for these and other convenient shortcuts.

Thanks, that really put me on the right track. I ended up using :results value verbatim and @2$1..@>$1='(nth (- @# 2) (split-string (org-sbe "my-values"))) so that I don't need the car.

Oh, I see: if you change the R block as mentioned, you produce a list of scalars. That's neat!
